# ftpClient.rename function not working within FTPUtility Class - using apache.commons.net

Tags: java, file-rename, ftp-client, apache-commons-net

I'm creating an upload app.

The upload works via FTP, but I then want to rename the file on the FTP server, but it doesn’t appear to work with the existing connection,
If I create a function that creates a new connection I can rename the file on the server (function in the FTPUtility class), but I don’t want to disconnect from the FTP and then create a new connection.
 I thought it would be possible to use the existing connection as its not closed, and the code is within the same class and variable
Any help would be greatly appreciated;

UploadTask.java

```
  public Void uploadFile() throws Exception {
        FTPUtility util = new FTPUtility(host, port, username, password);
        try {
            util.connect();            
            util.uploadFile(uploadFile, destDir);

            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            long totalBytesRead = 0;
            int percentCompleted = 0;
            long fileSize = uploadFile.length();

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                util.writeFileBytes(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                percentCompleted = (int) (totalBytesRead * 100 / fileSize);
                barUpdate1.setValue(percentCompleted);
            }
            String strFileName = uploadFile.getName();            
            System.out.println("the filename in uploadtask is: " +  strFileName);
            boolean bolRenamed = false;

//FILE RENAME - first line doesn’t work, second line does work as creates new connection
       bolRenamed = util.renameFileOnServer("test", "testrename.txt");   
         //    util.testFTPrenameWORKSseperateApp();

          inputStream.close();
            util.finish();

        } catch (FTPException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage(),
                    "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
            barUpdate1.setValue(0);
        //    cancel(true);
        } finally {
            util.disconnect();
```

FTPUtility.Java

```
public void uploadFile(File uploadFile, String destDir) throws FTPException {
        try {
            boolean success = ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(destDir);
            if (!success) {
                throw new FTPException("Could not change working directory to "
                        + destDir + ". The directory may not exist.");
            }

            success = ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            if (!success) {
                throw new FTPException("Could not set binary file type.");
            }

            outputStream = ftpClient.storeFileStream(uploadFile.getName());

 //TESTNIG TESTING TESTING        
  if (outputStream != null)
  {
      System.out.println("file exists");}
  else 
  {
      System.out.println("file doesnt exist");
     }  

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FTPException("uploadFile :@ Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

//DOESN’T WORK using existing connection

```
 public boolean renameFileOnServer(String fileName, String fileNameTo) throws FTPException 
    {
                boolean result = false;
                try {             
                        result = ftpClient.rename("B100.PDF", "newFile100.pdf");
                        if (result == true)
                        {
                                System.out.println("File renamed !");
                        } 
                        else
                        {

                throw new FTPException("FTP error in rename file on server");

                          //  System.out.println("File renaming failed ");
                        }
                }
               catch (IOException e) 
                {
                        System.err.println(e);
                }

    return result;
    }
```

This works fine
 //WORKS WORKS

```
 public void testFTPrenameWORKSseperateApp() throws IOException {
            FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
            boolean result;
            try {
                    // Connect to the localhost
                    ftpClient.connect("xxx");

                    // login to ftp server
                    result = ftpClient.login("xxx", "xxx");

                    if (result == true) 
                    {
                            System.out.println("Logged in Successfully !");
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                            System.out.println("Login Fail !");
                            return;
                    }
                    // Rename file.
                    result = ftpClient.rename("B100.PDF", "newFile100.pdf");
                    if (result == true)
                    {
                            System.out.println("File renamed !");
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                            System.out.println("File renaming failed ");
                    }

            } 
            catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) 
            {
                    System.err.println(e);
            }
            finally 
            {
                    try 
                    {
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                    }
                    catch (FTPConnectionClosedException e) 
                    {
                            System.err.println(e);
                    }
            }
    }  //eof function
```

Answer (score 0):

resolved renaming the file, moving the rename function under the closing stream and util.finish

```
  inputStream.close();
        util.finish();
        bolRenamed = util.renameFileOnServer(uploadFile.getName(), strFileNamePrefix);
```

but now receive an error even though the file is renamed,
the catch code is showing a msgbox from the start of the function run;

```
 try {
        uploadFile(); 
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage(),
                "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
       //barUpdate1.setValue(progress); 
     }
```